# How to add Cov2D at the end of GRU in keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to run a model with conv2d attached at the end of gru. The gru will return all the sequences which means the output of gru should be a batch of 28*28 matrices. Then I want to input them into a conv2d, since conv2d needs a 4d tensor, I reshape the tensor in the layer but there comes an error.

So I guess there is some problems with the reshape layer but searching through the net there seems no satisfied answer. Can anyone give some hints, thanks a lot.

```
def build_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    x = Input(input_shape)
    x = Embedding(10000, 64, input_length=28)(x)
    forw = GRU(14, return_sequences=True)(x)
    back = GRU(14, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True)(x)
    y = Concatenate(-1)([forw, back])
    y = Reshape((None,28,28,1))(y)
    y = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(y)
    y = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(y)
    y = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(y)
    y = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(y)
    y = Flatten()(y)
    y = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(y)
    return Model(x,y)
```

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 401, in call
    return K.reshape(inputs, (K.shape(inputs)[0],) + self.target_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1969, in reshape
    return tf.reshape(x, shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 7179, in reshape
    "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 529, in _apply_op_helper
    (input_name, err))
ValueError: Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

Comment: Do you know which exact line in your code caused the trouble? That will help.

Comment: Also this is on Keras document: return_sequences: Boolean. Whether to return the last output in the output sequence, or the full sequence. I'm not sure what this is talking about, so try  return_sequences = False.